# Why are my custom button styles not working?

Tags: html, css, button

I want to change my buttons so they don't just look like the default grey ones.

```css
.button {
border-top: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
background: #2b2b2b;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#262626), to(#2b2b2b));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
padding: 7px 14px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover {
border-top-color: #303030;
background: #303030;
color: #ffffff;
}
.button:active {
border-top-color: #2b2b2b;
background: #2b2b2b;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="window.location.href='https://itunes.apple.com/gb/podcast/canon-slade-digital-leaders/id588207792'">Find our Podcasts on iTunes ⇒</button>
```

But for some reason, the buttons don't look any different.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: remove the dot before button or asign a class 'button' to your button, then it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use:

```
.button {}
```

Use without dot:

```
button {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are styling the **class** `.button`... use `button` instead. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/yaf7M/)

Updated CSS:

```
button {
    border-top: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#262626), to(#2b2b2b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626, #2b2b2b);
    padding: 7px 14px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
button:hover {
    border-top-color: #303030;
    background: #303030;
    color: #ffffff;
}
button:active {
    border-top-color: #2b2b2b;
    background: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've removed the dots, button still no luck. Nothing's changed. :(

Comment: Where has "nothing changed," as you can see in the linked demo (in this answer) this approach works. So, have you changed the CSS in your page? Cleared the cache? Reloaded the page?

Comment: I'm not really entirely sure what's gone wrong, but I guess it isn't the button CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I typed

```css
.container0 {
  position: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}  
.container0 .btn0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 49.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container0 .btn0:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container0">
  <button class="btn0">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

This code works. Please check it

Comment: But I cant add more css buttons even when i try this